# Android Emulator Out of memory error when launched from snapshot

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I'm using the Android emulator to test my app. I made an AVD with snapshots enabled, setup as shown in the image:

[image]

When I run the app first time, everything works fine. When I update my app and re-run it, the app updates on the emulator with no problem.

However, when I close the emulator (saves to snapshot), then launch from snapshot, only the previous version of the app works. When I update the app and try to re-run, I get this error:

```
Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Out of memory
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Out of memory
Launch canceled!
```

Feel free to ask me any questions and please help.

Comment: delete the old avd and create a new avd that works fine

Comment: I am using snapshots to avoid deleting avd's. even when I create a new AVD, this problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you update your code, you periodically package and install it on the emulator. The emulator preserves the application and its state data across restarts, in a user-data disk partition. To ensure that the application runs properly as you update it, you may need to delete the emulator's user-data partition. To do so, start the emulator with the -wipe-data option. For more information about the user-data partition and other emulator storage, see Working with Emulator Disk Images.: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#apps